# Titanium appcelerator studio Installation issue

Tags: android, installation, cross-platform, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am facing problem with Installation of Titanium Studio.

I have set up all the required `Environment Variable's`

This is my `JAVA_HOME` variable `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25;`

This is mt `Path` Variable `C:\Development\android-sdk-windows;C:\Development\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools;C:\Development\android-sdk-windows\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinAnt\bin;D:\Android SDK\android-sdk_r16-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools;C:\Development\phonegap-2.9.0\lib\android;`

I have installed `jdk1.7.0_25 and JRE 7`.

Also I have given my path of Android SDK `D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk`, at Android SDK home variable.

But now when i try to connect Android sdk with Titanium Studio it is just showing me Installing Android and nothing is happening.

When i try to Run an Application it gives me an Error `It Appears that you do not have android SDK installed in your system please follow the instructions at the Dashboard to configure SDK`

I have followed same but not finding solution, Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you installed a 32 bit java in your system?

Comment: @Anand: nope its 64 bit only

Comment: @MahaveerMuttha try this http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Installing_the_Android_SDK

Comment: @Swap-IOS-Android: following the same but doing some mistake somewhere and unable to detect.

Comment: have jdk 1.6 solved your problem?

Comment: @Wahhab_mirza: nope i am still facing problem. Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.1.1, Titanium SDK version 3.1.1.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2013, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
[ERROR] :  Unable to detect Android SDK targets.
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

Comment: Try to install android sdk 2.2 and give your project celand build and would be better if u run the code in device

Comment: Ok if u think jdk problem has solved you could mark the thread as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-JavaDevelopmentKit)

> - The 32-bit version of the JDK is required regardless of whether Titanium is running on a 32-bit or 64-bit Windows system.
> - On Windows, Studio contains its own JRE, meaning you do not need to install the JDK before installing or launching Studio but will need it
>     to use the Titanium SDK.
> - Titanium Studio prompts you to install the JDK when installing the Android SDK from the Dashboard on Windows.

Try to install 32 bit java in your system.

Please refer [Compatibility and Download](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Installing_Oracle_JDK-section-29004850_InstallingOracleJDK-CompatibilityandDownload)

Comment: i have installed the 32 bit java also. if you can see in Envoirment Variable its x86 version and not 64 bit. but still not working, facing same issue.

Comment: The following link says that Titanium supports 1.6 http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-JavaDevelopmentKit

Answer (score 2):

Always have a good look at titanium compatibility matrix.Jdk 1.7 is not compatible until now only 1.6 is suitable for android

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-JavaDevelopmentKit

Thanks